# Calling functions that use inout arrays from a closure

Tags: swift

I decided to update a project that I had made during Swift beta 1 now that Swift 1.0 is out. There's a particular issue, however, that I can't seem to fix that came up as a result of the updated array semantics and `inout` keyword. Consider the following two functions (you can just paste them into a playground):

```
func bubbleSort<T : Comparable>(inout arr : [T]) {
    var numSwaps = 0
    do {
        numSwaps = 0
        for i in 0..<(arr.count - 1) {
            if arr[i] > arr[i + 1] {
                (arr[i], arr[i + 1]) = (arr[i + 1], arr[i])
                numSwaps++
            }
        }
    } while numSwaps != 0
}

func testFunc(sortFunc: ([Int]) -> ()) {
    sortFunc([5,4,3,2,1])
}
```

I can't seem to make the two work together. I tried using shorthand:

```
testFunc {bubbleSort(&$0)}
```

I also tried without shorthand:

```
testFunc { (arr: [Int]) -> () in
    bubbleSort(&arr)
}
```

In either case, I get errors:

[image: error screenshot]

Is this a bug, or am I screwing something up? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're running into is that method parameters are by default immutable and in-out functions are mutating. You can't use the closure shorthand, because you'll need to declare the closure's argument as mutable with the `var` keyword, like so:

```
func testFunc(sortFunc: ([Int]) -> ()) {
    sortFunc([5,4,3,2,1])
}

testFunc { (var arr: [Int]) -> () in
    bubbleSort(&arr)
}
```

Now you can call `bubbleSort` with `arr` as the in-out parameter.

Answer (score 2):

What you're running into is the change in beta 3 (if I recall correctly) where changing en element of an array became a `mutating` operation. Before that changing an element was a non-mutating operation, and therefore you can change an element on an `Array` constant; you just couldn't change its length. But since beta 3, to change an element on an array, it needs to be non-constant.

`bubbleSort` takes the array by reference (`inout`) because it needs to change the elements of the array and have it visible to the caller (prior to beta 3, it just took it by value). You can only pass a non-constant variable by reference. In the closure you wrote, `arr` is a constant (it's an array parameter not declared `var` or `inout`), therefore you cannot pass it by reference.

The obvious answer is that `arr` needs to be `var` or `inout`. Which one you need depends on what these functions are intended to do. What you have currently is discard the result of calls, which is pointless, so you are clearly not showing us what these functions are supposed to do.

@NakeCook's answer, simply make `arr` a `var`, makes it possible to pass it by reference, but it doesn't change the fact that the closure takes its argument by value (and the fact that `sortFunc` in `testFunc` is a pass-by-value function. That means `testFunc` gives an array to the function to sort, but does not care or want changes to be reflected back to it. If this is what you want, then that is the answer.

However, if `testFunc` is supposed to have an array, pass it to a sort function to sort, and wants to see changes to the array in its scope, then it needs to do something else:

```
func testFunc(sortFunc: (inout [Int]) -> ()) {
  var x = [5,4,3,2,1]
  sortFunc(&x)
}

testFunc { (inout arr: [Int]) -> () in
  bubbleSort(&arr)
}
```

In this case, the closure's parameter is declared as `inout` (so it's passed by reference), and also the `sortFunc` (in `testFunc`)'s type explicitly mentions that it takes its parameter by reference.